# Binomial Expansion - what went wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

When we apply binomial expansion $(1+z)^\alpha = \sum \dbinom{\alpha}{n} z^n$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1$, we have:

If $\alpha=-1$, then $(1+z)^{-1} = \sum \dbinom{-1}{n} z^n$. On the other hand $(1+z)^{-1} = (1-(-z))^{-1} = \sum (-1)^n z^n$.

But Taylor expansions about $0$ are unique  - and clearly these do match? What went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing went wrong because we have

$$ { -1 \choose n } = \frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots(-n)}{n!} = \frac{(-1)^n n!}{n!}=  (-1)^n.$$

Comment: To amuse yourself, you can check that the formula also works for $\alpha = 1$.